In my app with flutter my sidebar stops working once the user logs in and redirects to home
class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  late bool isLoggedIn = false;
  @override
  initState() {
    super.initState();
    _checkLoginStatus();
  }

  User? _user;
  void _checkLoginStatus() async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    isLoggedIn = prefs.getBool('isLoggedIn') ?? false;
    final user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
    if (user != null) {
      setState(() {
        _user = user;
      });
    }
    prefs.setBool('isLoggedIn', isLoggedIn);
  }

  MenuItem currentItem = MenuItems.home;
  final zoomDrawerController = ZoomDrawerController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ScreenUtilInit(
      child: Directionality(
        textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
        child: Builder(builder: (context) {
          return ZoomDrawer(
              menuScreen: Builder(
                builder: (context) => SidebarScreen(
                  currentItem: currentItem,
                  onSelectItem: (item) {
                    setState(() => currentItem = item);
                    ZoomDrawer.of(context)!.close();
                  },
                  isLoggedIn: isLoggedIn,
                  zoomDrawerController: zoomDrawerController,
                ),
              ),
              showShadow: true,
              style: DrawerStyle.style1,
              controller: zoomDrawerController,
              slideHeight: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
              mainScreen: getScreen(currentItem, isLoggedIn, _user));
        }),
      ),
    );
  }
}


///
Widget getScreen(
    MenuItem currentItem, bool isLoggedIn,User? user) {
  switch (currentItem) {
    case MenuItems.about:
      return const About();
    case MenuItems.register:
      return const RegisterScreen();
    case MenuItems.chat:
      return const About();
    case MenuItems.login:
      return const LoginScreen();

    default:
      return Home(
        isLoggedIn: isLoggedIn,user: user,
      );
  }
}




getscreen renders the home depending on the isLoggedIn state, when the sidebar stops working I have to restart the app to recognize the isLoggedIn and the sidebar opens normally and when I logout the same thing happens, it does not recognize the state.
Try passing the isLoggedIn state to the getScreen method to pass it as a parameter to Home() so that when the user logs in or logs out the home can be rendered and the zoomDrawerController does not crash since the isLoggedIn state is being updated.   Initially in the main.dart it is defined as late IsLoggedIn= false because it is a variable that can change.
